# MultiSelectListPreference defaultValues not working

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-multiselectlistpreference

I have a project that I am building in Android Studio. I've added the prebuilt preference screen with fragments which compiles and runs fine. I added a MultiSelectListPreference to one of the preference screens which displays fine and stores preference settings. However, the defaultValue is not working whether I add it via Java or XML. I have read the scores of other questions about how to do this. I know how. My question is what could cause it not to work as intended?

pref_general.xml

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_key_starting_addresses"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_addresses"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_addresses"
    android:entries="@array/empty_array"
    android:entryValues="@array/empty_array" />
```

PreferenceActivity.java

```
/**
 * This method autopopulates a MultiSelectListPreference with array values
 * loaded from XML.
 */
private void populateMultiSelectListPreference() {
    List<TypedArray> origins = ResourceHelper.getMultiTypedArray(mContext, "origins");
    CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[origins.size()];
    CharSequence[] values = new CharSequence[origins.size()];
    int counter = 0;
    for (TypedArray item : origins) {
        entries[counter] = item.getString(0);
        values[counter] = String.valueOf(counter);
        counter++;
    }

    final MultiSelectListPreference lp = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_starting_addresses));
    lp.setEntries(entries);
    lp.setDefaultValue(values);
    lp.setEntryValues(values);
}
```

arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="empty_array" />

<!-- a number of these are used to generate the MultiSelectListPreference
     titles and entry values-->
<array name="origins_0">
    <item>Text used for title</item>
    <item>data 1</item>
    <item>data 2</item>
</array>
```

I know that everything is working properly because debugging shows that `values` contains a valid Set and saving preferences works fine. This means that `lp.setEntryValues(values)` works and that `values` is a properly formatted Set. However, `lp.setDefaultValue(values)` has no effect. The checkboxes are all unchecked at first run. My goal is to have them all selected by default.

Yes, I have used the `Clean and rerun 'app'` command from Android Studio's Run menu between tests. Additionally, I've cleared the app cache manually on the device.

[EDIT]

With suggestions in comments, I have also tried the following modification.

```
private void populateMultiSelectListPreference() {
    List<TypedArray> origins = ResourceHelper.getMultiTypedArray(mContext, "origins");
    CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[origins.size()];
    CharSequence[] values = new CharSequence[origins.size()];
    Set<String> defaults = new HashSet<>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (TypedArray item : origins) {
        entries[counter] = item.getString(0);
        values[counter] = String.valueOf(counter);
        defaults.add(String.valueOf(counter));
        counter++;
    }

    final MultiSelectListPreference lp = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_starting_addresses));
    lp.setEntries(entries);
    lp.setEntryValues(values);
    lp.setDefaultValue(defaults);
}
```

Comment: where do you call `populateMultiSelectListPreference`?

Comment: There is no reason it could not work directly in XML, can you post what you tried with XML and the arrays associated?

Comment: Do not  keep the array empty . Try to add items to the string-array in arrays.xml .

Comment: @pskink It's called from the onCreate method of the PreferenceFragment.

Comment: @YoannHercouet The default values are dynamically generated as incrementing numbers based a number of individual arrays that exist elsewhere. I cannot assign it in XML since it is dynamic.

Comment: try this: http://pastebin.com/KhRU5KLn, the problem is with private method `dispatchSetInitialValue` in Preference.java wich is called only from `Preference#onAttachedToHierarchy`

Comment: @WannaBeGeek The empty array has nothing to do with the defaultValue. It is only a place holder for the title and value arrays and is necessary when adding them dynamically. You cannot have a MultiSelectPreference in XML without assigning the `android:entries` and `android:entryValues` attributes.

Comment: @Nilpo Ok . Does it work for static values and not for dynamic values?

Comment: @WannaBeGeek I tried with static XML arrays. The titles and values work perfectly, but the defaultValue does not. In XML, I set `android:entryValues` and `android:defaultValue` to point to the same array. The should have made all of the checkboxes selected, but it does not. The default value does not appear to work from either Java or XML. Google searches show a lot of people having the same issue. In fact, I've not found a single working example yet anywhere on the web. I'm beginning the thing I need to submit a bug report.

Comment: did you try the code i posted?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it didn't work with the Set<String> either. Android docs show that the setDefaultValue method accepts an Object, but the method itself is actually inherited from the Preference class. I wonder if the MultiSelectListPreference class was supposed to override this with its own implementation.

Comment: did you use my exact code? with no modifications? also use the unique `android:key` since there is a chance that your property was already set

Comment: @pskink I updated my post with the code I tried.

Comment: so try this: http://pastebin.com/KhRU5KLn, this is the preference you should add in your xml file like <path.to.your.custom.preference.MSLP />

Comment: Took me a minute to figure out the XML part. I didn't see your last comment in time. That works. e0 and e2 are selected. e1 is not.

Comment: note that i used Set<String> by trial and error: simple `CharSequence[]` made a cast exception in `MultiSelectListPreference` - i had to take a look into its sources

Comment: I did that before as well. Set<String> does not work outside of the extended class. Passing a Set<String> to setDefaultValue doesn't work. See my edit above.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I tried this: http://pastebin.com/sxSSTuyG and it worked. However, using my values did not. It turns out that you cannot use a string that is numeric. Clearly there is a bug in Android. The solution for now is to use a different naming convention and avoid numeric strings.

Comment: I think I'm running into the issue described here: https://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/30/beware-of-preference-default-values-in-xml/

Comment: And I'm back to square one. Using non-numeric values is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess here but I wonder if the reason is just the order you are calling your values, I would set the default values in the last step considering the full list should be initialized first:

```
final MultiSelectListPreference lp = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_starting_addresses));
lp.setEntries(entries);
lp.setEntryValues(values);
lp.setDefaultValue(values);
```

Comment: The order of the methods doesn't seem to have any effect. I also tried with a suggestion from another comment using a Set<String> instead of the CharSequence[]. Neither one worked even when calling `setDefaultValue` last. Interestingly enough, the Android documentation says that setDefaultValue accepts an Object as a parameter. Further investigation shows that it is inherited from the Preference class. I wonder is the MSLP was supposed to override this with a custom implementation.